# java write translations in application.properties

Tags: java, properties, internationalization

I would like to know how can I write application.properties files. Actually I would like to load the translations from each file, check them if they are well translated and, in case they are missing, I would like to be notified about them and be able to change them.

Is there any way to easily access the load the localization files and then write them?

I can load them using the classical reader and write them in the same way but it's a lot of work that need to be taken care of if I follow this path.

Comment: I know. But I need to write a small program to organize those files.